# expo invariant violation rncsafeareaprovider error on ios

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I have developed an app with react native using expo. I published the app to expo and it is working fine with android but it is giving error on ios. On some digging I also tried to install react-native-webview but that also did not work. How I can fix this problem.

Comment: please read https://docs.expo.io/workflow/using-libraries/ - you need to use `expo install library_name` to install the library and get the correct version

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that when you were installing other dependencies, you have duplicated `react-native-safe-area-context`. For example, if you have installed `@react-native-community/masked-view` or some other package containing this you can get this error. You simply have to remove the duplicate.

`rm -rf node_modules/expo/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context` is one solution.
But remove the module you absolutely don't want.